# How to get more than 2000 records from custom object?

Tags: soql, php, governorlimits

**Problem**

I'm trying to make a standard query to get all records from salesforce custom object. I'm using SOAP API.

I have more than 40k records in object.

But salesforce OFFSET limit 2000 record. which is give error.

So, I have try out some workaround solution,

> SELECT Id, Name, CreatedDate FROM Account WHERE CreatedDate >
>   "Last-Returned-Created-Date" ORDER BY CreatedDate LIMIT 2000

But this query not work, if there was more than one object created at that exact date and time.

**Question**

Is there any way to do this?

Actually i am implementing logic in PHP and calling salesforce get API with above mention SOQL query as query parameter.

Comment: yes. You can do Id > last returned id

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the SOAP API, just use [queryMore](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_querymore.htm#topic-title). There's no need to use LIMIT/OFFSET, as the system will keep feeding you records until the end. The basic process looks like this:

```
QueryResult qr = connector.query(queryString);
while(true) {
  // Process qr.records
  if(qr.done) {
    break;
  }
  qr = connector.queryMore(qr.queryLocator);
}
```

A more specific example is included in the documentation:

```
public void queryRecords() {
   QueryResult qResult = null;
   try {
      String soqlQuery = "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Contact";
      qResult = connection.query(soqlQuery);
      boolean done = false;
      if (qResult.getSize() > 0) {
         System.out.println("Logged-in user can see a total of "
            + qResult.getSize() + " contact records.");
         while (!done) {
            SObject[] records = qResult.getRecords();
            for (int i = 0; i < records.length; ++i) {
               Contact con = (Contact) records[i];
               String fName = con.getFirstName();
               String lName = con.getLastName();
               if (fName == null) {
                  System.out.println("Contact " + (i + 1) + ": " + lName);
               } else {
                  System.out.println("Contact " + (i + 1) + ": " + fName
                        + " " + lName);
               }
            }
            if (qResult.isDone()) {
               done = true;
            } else {
               qResult = connection.queryMore(qResult.getQueryLocator());
            }
         }
      } else {
         System.out.println("No records found.");
      }
      System.out.println("\nQuery succesfully executed.");
   } catch (ConnectionException ce) {
      ce.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Note that if you're really trying to do that sort of pagination, consider sorting by Id:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE Id > 'Last-Returned-Id' ORDER BY Id ASC LIMIT 2000
```